# Copy SQL Data from a table in one database to one in another database

Tags: sql-server-2008, vb.net-2010

I have two programmes that use the same data from one table, I wanted to know is there an easy way of copying the data from one database table to another one in another database?

Comment: Are these databases on the same server?

Comment: Use a three-part name (database.schema.table) or Linked Server and four part name(server.databse.schema.table) in a simple INSERT ... SELECT ... statement. All the relevant concepts are readily searchable in Books OnLine.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a simple question readily answered by BOL.

Comment: Yes the Databases are on the same server.